# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'image'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am getting an error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'image'.
```

I use xml and asp.net.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.XPath" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            binddata();
            binddata2();
        }

        if (Session["userlevel"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
        if (Session["error_msg"] != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = Session["error_msg"].ToString();
            Session["error_msg"] = null;
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    void binddata()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultImage.xml"));
            gv.DataSource = ds;
            gv.DataBind();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = e.Message;
            ds = null;
        }
    }
    protected void Editdata(object s, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        binddata();
    }
    protected void Deletedata(object s, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        binddata();
        DataSet ds = gv.DataSource as DataSet;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
        ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultImage.xml"));
        binddata();

        Session["error_msg"] = "The welcome image was deleted successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }
    protected void Canceldata(object s, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        binddata();
    }
    protected void Updatedata(object s, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        int i = e.RowIndex;
        string id = (gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtimage") as TextBox).Text;
        string name = (gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txttext") as TextBox).Text;
        gv.EditIndex = -1;
        binddata();
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)gv.DataSource;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["image"] = id;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["text"] = name;
        ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultImage.xml"));
        binddata();

        Session["error_msg"] = "The welcome image was updated successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }
    protected void pageddata(object s, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        binddata();
    }

    protected void insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binddata();
        DataSet ds = gv.DataSource as DataSet;
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr[0] = Image1.Text;
        dr[1] = Text1.Text;
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        ds.AcceptChanges();
        ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultImage.xml"));
        binddata();
        Image1.Text = string.Empty;
        Text1.Text = string.Empty;

        Session["error_msg"] = "The welcome image was added successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------

    void binddata2()
    {
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            ds2.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultBefore.xml"));
            gv2.DataSource = ds2;
            gv2.DataBind();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = e.Message;
            ds2 = null;
        }
    }
    protected void Editdata2(object s, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        binddata2();
    }
    protected void Deletedata2(object s, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        binddata2();
        DataSet ds2 = gv2.DataSource as DataSet;
        ds2.Tables[0].Rows[gv2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
        ds2.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultBefore.xml"));
        binddata2();

        Session["error_msg"] = "The before-after image was deleted successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }
    protected void Canceldata2(object s, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv2.EditIndex = -1;
        binddata2();
    }
    protected void Updatedata2(object s, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        int i = e.RowIndex;
        string id = (gv2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtimagebefore") as TextBox).Text;
        gv2.EditIndex = -1;
        binddata2();
        DataSet ds2 = (DataSet)gv2.DataSource;
        ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["image"] = id;
        ds2.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultBefore.xml"));
        binddata2();

        Session["error_msg"] = "The before-after image was updated successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }
    protected void pageddata2(object s, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gv2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        binddata2();
    }

    protected void insert2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        binddata2();
        DataSet ds2 = gv2.DataSource as DataSet;
        DataRow dr2 = ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dr2[0] = ImageBefore.Text;
        ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2);
        ds2.AcceptChanges();
        ds2.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("../App_Data/DefaultBefore.xml"));
        binddata2();
        ImageBefore.Text = string.Empty;

        Session["error_msg"] = "The before-after image was added successfully";
        Response.Redirect("AdminDefault.aspx");
    }    


</script>
<div id="content">
    <div class="about">

 <b><i><asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" /></i></b> 
 <h3>Add a welcome image and text</h3>  <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblImage" runat="server" Text="Image Path" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Image1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
    ControlToValidate="Image1" Font-Italic="true"
    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(Required)" 
    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AddWelcome" />
 <br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Image Text" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
    ControlToValidate="Text1" Font-Italic="true"
    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(Required)" 
    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AddWelcome" />

    <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" onclick="insert" ValidationGroup="AddWelcome" />
    <br /><br />

    <asp:GridView ID="gv" Width="80%" runat="server" OnRowEditing="Editdata" AllowSorting="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="pageddata" OnRowDeleting="Deletedata" BorderColor="Black"
    OnRowUpdating="Updatedata" OnRowCancelingEdit="Canceldata" AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="white" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblimage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("image") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtimage" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("image") %>' />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtimage" Font-Italic="true"
                    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(Required)" 
                    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Welcome" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image text" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("text") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txttext" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("text") %>' />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
                    ControlToValidate="txttext" Font-Italic="true"
                    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="(Required)" 
                    ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Welcome" />

                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ValidationGroup="Welcome" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ValidationGroup="Welcome" />
        </Columns>

        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Maroon" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"/>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Crimson" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Maroon" />
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" BackColor="Maroon" Font-Bold="true" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="AntiqueWhite" />


    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br /><br /><br />





xml file

DefaultBefore.xml

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<images xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <image>
    App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter1.jpg
  </image>
  <image>
    App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter3.jpg
  </image>
  <image>
    App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter5.jpg
  </image>
</images>



DefaultImage.xml

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <images>
    <image>
    App_Themes/theme/html/images/title1.jpg
  </image>
    <text>
    A dog is a man's best friend... Dog Club is a dogs best friend.
  </text>
  </images>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your XML:

```
<images>
    <image>
        <path>
            App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter1.jpg
        </path>
    </image>
    <image>
        <path>
            App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter3.jpg
        </path>
    </image>
    <image>
        <path>
            App_Themes/theme/html/images/beforeafter5.jpg
        </path>
    </image>
</images>
```

Then modify your data binding expression:

```
<%# Eval("path") %>
```